# I need help for a facial recognition and voice recognition project (Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: python, opencv, email, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition

I'm working on a Python project using my Raspberry Pi, that essentially is an email alert monitoring system, that sends an email if it detects a face or if someone says "Help" in the room.

I already have a working code for the facial recognition and other for the voice commands, but I needed to have these two in the same code, for example:

The facial recognition is running and takes a pic of the face it detects and sends it via email, but in the same code, if the person in the room says "Help", the cam will also take a photo and send it via email (even if it doesn't detect any face at all), but it needs to work simmultaneously.

That's the code for the facial recognition that's fully working:

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import face_recognition
import imutils
import pickle
import time
import cv2
import requests

import speech_recognition as sr

import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
 
fromaddr = "XXXX@XXX.XXX"   
toaddr = "XXXX@XXX.XXX"
 
mail = MIMEMultipart()
 
mail['De'] = fromaddr
mail['Para'] = toaddr
mail['Subject'] = "MONITORAMENTO RASPBERRY"



currentname = "Desconhecido"

encodingsP = "encodings.pickle"

cascade = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"

def send_message(name):
            
    body = "A face de " + name + " foi detectado no Quarto do Pedro! Veja as imagens em anexo."        
    mail.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    print (name)
    attachment = open("image.jpg", "rb")
    image=MIMEImage(attachment.read())
    attachment.close()
    mail.attach(image)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, "XXXXXXXX")
    text = mail.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()     


#Carrega os encodings para o reconhecimento facial
data = pickle.loads(open(encodingsP, "rb").read())
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade)


#Inicia o streaming de video
vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True).start()
time.sleep(2.0)

microfone = sr.Recognizer()

fps = FPS().start()

#Looping que realiza o reconhecimento facial e cria o box em volta da face.
while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


    rects = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, 
        minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

    
    boxes = [(y, x + w, y + h, x) for (x, y, w, h) in rects]


    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)
    names = []

    
    for encoding in encodings:
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(data["encodings"],
            encoding)
        name = "Desconhecido"

        if True in matches:
            matchedIdxs = [i for (i, b) in enumerate(matches) if b]
            counts = {}

            for i in matchedIdxs:
                name = data["names"][i]
                counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + 1

            name = max(counts, key=counts.get)
            
            if currentname != name:
                currentname = name
                print(currentname)
    
                img_name = "image.jpg"
                cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
                print('Tirando a foto.')
                
                #Envia Email
                send_message(name)


        names.append(name)


    for ((top, right, bottom, left), name) in zip(boxes, names):
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom),
            (0, 255, 225), 2)
        y = top - 15 if top - 15 > 15 else top + 15
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            .8, (0, 255, 255), 2)
            

    #Inicia o stream na tela
    cv2.imshow("Reconhecimento facial esta rodando...", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    #A tecla q encerra o loop.
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

    fps.update()
    


fps.stop()
print("[INFO] Tempo percorrido: {:.2f}".format(fps.elapsed()))
print("[INFO] Media de FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))


#encerra o stream
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

And that's the separate code that's also working for the voice command:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import picamera
import cv2
import time

import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

fromaddr = "xxxxx@gmail.com"   
toaddr = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com"
 
mail = MIMEMultipart()
 
mail['De'] = fromaddr
mail['Para'] = toaddr
mail['Subject'] = "MONITORAMENTO - QUARTO PEDRO"
body = "Foi detectada a palavra socorro no quarto do pedro!"
data=''

def sendMail(data):
    mail.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    attachment = open('image_teste.jpg', 'rb')
    image=MIMEImage(attachment.read())
    attachment.close()
    mail.attach(image)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, "xxxxxxx")
    text = mail.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()

def capture_image():
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(5)
    camera.capture('image_teste.jpg')
    camera.stop_preview()
    time.sleep(1)
    sendMail(data)

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.awb_mode= 'auto'
camera.brightness=55

while True:
    #Habilita o microfone do usuario
    microfone = sr.Recognizer()
    
    #usando o microfone
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        
        #Chama um algoritmo de reducao de ruidos no som
        #microfone.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        
        #Frase para o usuario dizer algo
        print("Diga alguma coisa: ")
        
        #Armazena o que foi dito numa variavel
        audio = microfone.listen(source)
        
    try:
        
        #Passa a variavel para o algoritmo reconhecedor de padroes
        frase = microfone.recognize_google(audio,language='pt-BR')
    
        
        #Retorna a frase pronunciada
        print("Voce disse: " + frase)
        if frase == 'Socorro':
            capture_image()
            print('Tirando a foto.')
        
    #Se nao reconheceu o padrao de fala, exibe a mensagem
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Nao entendi")
```

Can you give me and idea of what can I do to make the first code have this "Help" command and at the same time still work for facial recognition? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into multiprocessing? Or threading?

Comment: I tried to run these 2 codes simultaneously in these 2 files, but I'm using a raspberry Pi 3 and it didn't work I imagine due to harware limitations. I thought that maybe the voice part could be inserted in the loop from the first code somehow

Comment: I think the reason why they don't work at the same time is that you open the camera in both. Why do you need the camera for the voice recognition script? Can't you rewrite it such that it doesn't use a camera?

Comment: You are correct Paul, that is also the reason! The voice recognition script also needs to take a picture and send it via email. In this case, it would only send the email, but no pictures attached, right?

Comment: Yes, if you remove the camera from the voice recognition script, you won't get a picture (but you can send an email). If you absolutely need that picture, I'm afraid things are going to be more complicated. You probably need to design a multithreaded script, where the face and the voice recongition run on separate threads and have access to the same camera.

Comment: Ok, got it. I'll take a look into multithreading in Python then. Thanks for your help Paul!

Comment: You are processing continuos frames for the facial recognition part, right? What if you store the latest frame used for the image processing part. If the sound command triggers the system, it can fetch the latest frame stored and attach it to the email. The idea is, if you are continuously processing frames for facial recognition, you might as well store the latest captured frame and re-use that instead of taking a new frame. Of course, this depends on the sampling interval of your frame stream and if you are using full-sized frames for the facial recognition part.